# Is my 2017 Trek Fuel EX 5 Stealth internally routed dropper seatpost compatible?

Tags: seatpost, upgrades

I have got a 2017 Trek Fuel EX 5. After Christmas I may be upgrading it with a dropper seatpost.

I would like to know if it is compatible with an internally routed dropper seatpost.

Comment: The following was previously provided as an answer:


-2
down vote
At the moment we have a quartet of Trek bikes in the house, including two road bikes and two Fuel-series MTBs. I've found Trek customer service to be very responsive to questions put to them online via the Trek web site, so I'd suggest you contact them directly and report back what you learn.

Answer (score 1):

I googled the current Trek Fuel EX bikes a bit.

The EX series feature internally routed shift and brake cables the down tube, with entry points near the head tube.

The EX 9 comes with internally routed dropper post, and seems to share the frame with the EX 5, so I'd say yes.

Answer (score 0):

You could check if you have a hole to insert the droppers cable/hose into the frame. It should either be in the seattube ( which would include some kind of cable guides on the downtube ) or somewhere around the headtube.
If one of these is available you are good to go.

Apart from that I can't think of any newer frame which isn't compatible with internal dropper posts. Therfore it should fit just fine.